# Application name in app itself

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

Is it a good practice to write the app name in the app itself? Say below the navigation bar or status bar?

Comment: Please ask your question correctly, no one understand this line.

Answer (score 2):

you can write your app name in navigation bar .

Answer (score 2):

i think good practice is to put the app logo at the navigation bar. but the most best thing for a dveleoper is to read the apple guidlines for iOS here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its a good practice to write name of the app on the first view of the app. You can chagne the name later on according to the current view.